# Should I organize my react redux reducer composition based on the calls made OR based on the state a reducer manages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I'm learning to build a pokedex app that gives you info about a pokemon after you type in a name and hit submit. It has to go through 2 calls to get the right info, with the 1st getting its height and weight, and then 2nd getting its description (ex. "Charmander can usually be found in hot areas..."). Below is my action breakdown.

```
export const fetchPokemon = function (pokemonName) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestPokemon(pokemonName))
    const requestURL = `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`
    return $.ajax({
      url: requestURL,
    }).done(function (data) {
      dispatch(receivePokemon(data))
      return fetchPokemonDescription(pokemonName)
    }).done(function (res) {
      dispatch(receivePokemonDescription(res))
    })
  }
}

...

export const fetchPokemonDescription = function (pokemonName) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestPokemonDescription(pokemonName))
    const requestURL = `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${pokemonName}/`
    return $.ajax({
      url: requestURL,
    })
  }
}
```

Should I have a separate reducer for each call? Looking at the docs about [reducer composition](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) I'm not sure if it would make it cleaner to have 1 reducer vs 2 reducers. The 2 calls are not dependent on each other per say, but each different pokemon input will need to make both calls and the data coming back from both belongs to one pokemon so I was thinking it should be in one reducer handling one part of the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 1 reducer in your case.

It would be useful to see your state structure, but I think that you have something like:

```
currentPokemon: {
  name: ...
  height: ...
  weight: ...
  description: ...
}
```

If this is the case, I would use 1 reducer, because you manage just 1 branch of the state (currentPokemon).

The reducer will switch the action: in one case it will update height and weight, in the other the description:

```
export default function currentPokemonReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case DATA_RECEIVED:
      return {
        ...state,
        height: action.payload.height,
        weight: action.payload.weight
      }
    case DESCRIPTION_RECEIVED:
      return {
        ...state,
        description: action.payload
      }

    ...

    default:
      return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX call you are making should be paired with an action type. You should then return the the type and your payload, which I'm assuming based on your code, you intend to be to request responses.

```
//Now sure where these functional are define or what they do, but I'll assume they are selectors of some sort?
export const fetchPokemon = function (pokemonName) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestPokemon(pokemonName))
    const requestURL = `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`
    return $.ajax({
      url: requestURL,
    }).done(function (data) {
      dispatch(receivePokemon(data))
      return fetchPokemonDescription(pokemonName)
    }).done(function (res) {
      dispatch(receivePokemonDescription(res))
    })
  }
}
```

you're action might look something like this:

```
const data = fetchPokemon(Charmander);
//this can be defined somewhere else in your app, should not be in your actions file.    

export const pokemonAction(data) {
  return {
    type: "GET_POKEMON_NAME",
    payload: data.name
  }
}

//repeat for any other call
```

Best practice is to have your types defined separately so that they can be pulled into you actions files and reducer files. A lot of how you build your actions and reducers will depend on your response objects.

```
export const getPokemonReducer(state= {}, action) {
  if(action.type === "GET_POKEMON_NAME") {
    return {
     ...state,
     [pokemonName]: action.payload
    }
   if(action.type === "GET_POKEMON_DESC") {
    return {
     ...state,
     [pokemonDesc]: action.payload
    }
}
```

Reducers can be used in many different ways depending on how you want to shape your state. You should think about how you would like to use this information through out your application. The above example would give a single property, lets call it "Pokemon", and that properties value is an object that the above two properties.

For example if you want to pull in just the name and don't want to pull it in as `this.props.pokemon.pokemonName` then maybe you would consider having a separate reducer. I would also consider looking into abstractions such as `axios` and `redux-promise` which make asynchronous calls much easier to manage in redux.